# excel / VBA - Data Distribution

Tags: excel, vba

Warm Morning.

I would like to assign user name to a sheet which have the data to work by them.

Let say I have 350 Case study tickets to share to 22 student.

how to i do it??? Need to share the case ticket equally or near for every one.

for this case should be atlease 15 for every one or for some one may reach 16 /17 not a problem.

Kindly help me in this .............

Sheet 1

```
Stud Name
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF
GG
HH
II
JJ
KK
LL
MM
NN
OO
PP
QQ
RR
SS
TT
UU
VV
```

Sheet 2

```
Case ID's
D08457P
D24023
B03890
B03894
B00475
D02275
D02484
D12559
D04526
D04527
D49651
D49661
D49662
B81263
D04445
W00163P
D12034
D02427
E14005
D19521-3
D19521-4
D00690
D10646
D08206
D10244
B03642-1
D05404P
D05404-1
D05405-2
D10224
D03752
B06770
B26687
D26724
D26736
D11102
D06034
D02734
B10780
D10777
B02516
B04854
B02530
C06558
B81647
B81648
B02717
C81384
C81396
D08465
D14773
C14524-3
D14550
D14559
D09113
D09122
D83314
D83319
B25438
D25435
D81397
B14806
D14807
D14823
D21950
C35978
D38750
D38753P
D87178
D18595
D85838
B00227
B00228
D02002
D81016
D04880
D02272
D03502
D02448
D03199
D02169
D03047
B06467
D09275
D09287
C81515
D11495
D02856
D81144
D06682
D17530
D17562
B16804
D16813
D16822
D05129
W00209
B38786-2
B38853
B38860
B38867P
B38867-1
B38875
B38883
B38889
B83523
B83524
D38870
D10938
B04572
D23029-1
D23065
B06968
B24466
D24468P
B82288
B82289
B82290
D13064
D13065
D04040-1
C13958
D14002
B17932
B17940
D17944
D81223
D02629
C01451
D01449
B11591
D11585
D11588
D11597
D11598
B04746
B07800
D07798
B26740
D84601
C10256
D81889
D84666
D84676
D03678
B11165
D11162
D23757
B33828
B33843
D33845
D33851
D33855
D33857
D82528
B02984
D11052
D00090
D02511
D01666
D01671
D05085
D10059
D05723
D14007
D14025
C01302
C03382
D00008
C13464
B05936
B02765
D81911
C11907
D02411
D02531
D13879
D13883
D03630
B19277
B82771
D49639
D20119
D08779
D08780P
D08785
B14819
D08018
D08028P
D08038
D08039
C81463
C86333
D13907
D13908
B36126
C36082
D36105
D36111
D36128
D87174
D02009
D00930
B04013
D04008
B06939
D06928
D06935
D06936
D06940
B03253
D04443
D03050
D05187
D04776
B10005
D09998
B03491
B12270
D12229
D12244
D06672
D05759
D02715
D47895
C26222
D13338
D37177
D37185
D07653P
D07653-4
D04883
D02532
D81966
E06977P
B08182
E16920
D03827
D04349
B04659P
B04659-1
D36203
D36206
D18071
D82132
D82133
D83345
D83346
D83348
D11709
D10254
D14098
D84649
D84672
D03649
D33825
D08626
D17695
D05549
D05552
D06360
D06149
D10453
D10511
D10517
D10534
D18791
B00353
C02068
D04258
D22169
D07259
D19377
D19387
C83047
B12385
D19694P
D04436
B02730
D05268
D17514
D17528
D17529
D17531
D17542
D04565
B07643
D37168
D10280
D09196
D09210
D14367
D06604
D04418P
C03913
D04152P
B36141
D02780
B12833
D02488
B10644
C05708
D11565
D85529
D03957
D05216
B00053
D11607
C81980
D08735
D06295
B08173
B84677
B04674
D00560P
B07903-3
B08038-1
C00219
D81550
D18488
D11990-2
D12044
D02608
D19585-2
D19599-2
D81128
B09349
D09014
D03584
D02832
D06170
C81758
B06689
D02789
D02355
B27537
D27539
D27540
B25430P
C03889
D06472
B38823
B81421
B24482
B82699
D24469
D03256
D17939
D11690
D16924
D81468
C00381
D00283
D00373
C07313
D04722
D04723P
D06147
D03779
D03824
D03825
D03652
D04801
C02639
D00053
C81933
D03908
D01293
D15980
D10252
D04265
D06981
D04150
C00025
B03251
D81044


Sheet 3 
Case ID's
D08457P
D24023
B03890
B03894
B00475
D02275
D02484
D12559
D04526
D04527
D49651
D49661
D49662
B81263
D04445
W00163P
D12034
D02427
E14005
D19521-3
D19521-4
D00690
D10646
D08206
D10244
B03642-1
D05404P
D05404-1
D05405-2
D10224
D03752
B06770
B26687
D26724
D26736
D11102
D06034
D02734
B10780
D10777
B02516
B04854
B02530
C06558
B81647
B81648
B02717
C81384
C81396
D08465
D14773
C14524-3
D14550
D14559
D09113
D09122
D83314
D83319
B25438
D25435
D81397
B14806
D14807
D14823
D21950
C35978
D38750
D38753P
D87178
D18595
D85838
B00227
B00228
D02002
D81016
D04880
D02272
D03502
D02448
D03199
D02169
D03047
B06467
D09275
D09287
C81515
D11495
D02856
D81144
D06682
D17530
D17562
B16804
D16813
D16822
D05129
W00209
B38786-2
B38853
B38860
B38867P
B38867-1
B38875
B38883
B38889
B83523
B83524
D38870
D10938
B04572
D23029-1
D23065
B06968
B24466
D24468P
B82288
B82289
B82290
D13064
D13065
D04040-1
C13958
D14002
B17932
B17940
D17944
D81223
D02629
C01451
D01449
B11591
D11585
D11588
D11597
D11598
B04746
B07800
D07798
B26740
D84601
C10256
D81889
D84666
D84676
D03678
B11165
D11162
D23757
B33828
B33843
D33845
D33851
D33855
D33857
D82528
B02984
D11052
D00090
D02511
D01666
D01671
D05085
D10059
D05723
D14007
D14025
C01302
C03382
D00008
C13464
B05936
B02765
D81911
C11907
D02411
D02531
D13879
D13883
D03630
B19277
B82771
D49639
D20119
D08779
D08780P
D08785
B14819
D08018
D08028P
D08038
D08039
C81463
C86333
D13907
D13908
B36126
C36082
D36105
D36111
D36128
D87174
D02009
D00930
B04013
D04008
B06939
D06928
D06935
D06936
D06940
B03253
D04443
D03050
D05187
D04776
B10005
D09998
B03491
B12270
D12229
D12244
D06672
D05759
D02715
D47895
C26222
D13338
D37177
D37185
D07653P
D07653-4
D04883
D02532
D81966
E06977P
B08182
E16920
D03827
D04349
B04659P
B04659-1
D36203
D36206
D18071
D82132
D82133
D83345
D83346
D83348
D11709
D10254
D14098
D84649
D84672
D03649
D33825
D08626
D17695
D05549
D05552
D06360
D06149
D10453
D10511
D10517
D10534
D18791
B00353
C02068
D04258
D22169
D07259
D19377
D19387
C83047
B12385
D19694P
D04436
B02730
D05268
D17514
D17528
D17529
D17531
D17542
D04565
B07643
D37168
D10280
D09196
D09210
D14367
D06604
D04418P
C03913
D04152P
B36141
D02780
B12833
D02488
B10644
C05708
D11565
D85529
D03957
D05216
B00053
D11607
C81980
D08735
D06295
B08173
B84677
B04674
D00560P
B07903-3
B08038-1
C00219
D81550
D18488
D11990-2
D12044
D02608
D19585-2
D19599-2
D81128
B09349
D09014
D03584
D02832
D06170
C81758
B06689
D02789
D02355
B27537
D27539
D27540
B25430P
C03889
D06472
B38823
B81421
B24482
B82699
D24469
D03256
D17939
D11690
D16924
D81468
C00381
D00283
D00373
C07313
D04722
D04723P
D06147
D03779
D03824
D03825
D03652
D04801
C02639
D00053
C81933
D03908
D01293
D15980
D10252
D04265
D06981
D04150
C00025
B03251
D81044
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any *VBA* for this.  Say both lists are in column **A** of their respective sheets.  In **B2** of `Sheet1` enter:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-2)*16,0)
```

and copy this across through cell **Q2**

then copy cells **B2** through **Q2** downwards:

[image]

Assign any leftovers by hand.

**Note:**

Any single column can be mapped into a 2D table of arbitrary dimensions, either in column order or row order.  The same is true for a single row of data.

In a similar fashion any 2D table can be mapped into a single column or single row.